# "me" in a subject postion

Tags: grammar

In the following lyric, a song by Ed Sheeran, I believe the highlighted word should be "I" because it is part of the subject. Can you explain it from a grammatical viewpoint?

> The club isn't the best place to find a lover. So the bar is where I go.
>   **Me** and my friends at the table doing shots. Drinking fast and then we talk slow.

Comment: It's not a complete sentence.  How do you know that "me" is the subject?

Comment: *Me* isn’t the subject, *me and my friends* is.  If it were a complete sentence, this would be very important!

Answer (score 2):

> Me and my friends at the table doing shots.

*Doing* is the present participle form of *do*.  This whole phrase isn't a complete sentence, and would be normally something that comes after the main verb in a sentence.  The main verb is missing or *elided* - and it's a phenomenon of spoken speech or an artistic choice to sound conversational or familiar.

Let's say you are showing someone pictures of your family on a projector and providing a quick description of each picture.  Saying "This is a picture of ..." will get tiring and repetitive, so you will tend to leave it out after a couple of descriptions.

> [First picture appears] This is a picture of my dog.
>
> [Second picture appears] Here's my cat doing something silly.
>
> [Third picture appears] My grandmother yelling at the dog and cat.

That's what's happening in the example sentence.  The writer has a picture in his mind and is describing it in a similar style.  There's a lot of verbs that could fit in there:

> [Here is] me and my friends at the table doing shots.
>
> [This is] me and my friends at the table doing shots.
>
> [Where you can see] me and my friends at the table doing shots.

The exact verb isn't important because the writer is simply trying to share an image with you.